# can't seem to install dahdi on my server

Tags: linux, asterisk

I am trying to install the dahdi module on my server but it keeps failing when i run the make all command.  See below:

```
root@server:~/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.2+2.6.2# make all
make -C linux all
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.2+2.6.2/linux'
make -C drivers/dahdi/firmware firmware-loaders
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.2+2.6.2/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.2+2.6.2/linux/drivers/dahdi/firmware'
You do not appear to have the sources for the 3.9.3-x86-linode52 kernel installed.
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.2+2.6.2/linux'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

So then I typed the following to confirm that I do have 3.9.3-x86-linode52 kernal installed:

```
root@server:~/dahdi-linux-complete-2.6.2+2.6.2# uname -a
Linux server 3.9.3-x86-linode52 #1 SMP Mon May 20 09:32:28 EDT 2013 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

Why does dahdi complain that sources for 3.9.3-x86-linode52 is missing even though uname says it is there?

Comment: Why do you think that because a certain kernel version is active the kernel *source code* is installed as well? There is no such correlation and you have to install the source for the running kernel, however this is done with Linode.

Comment: I assumed due to inexperience

Comment: You'll need to contact Linode for information on how to install the kernel headers corresponding to their custom kernel, or use pvgrub to use your own kernel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured things out and wrote a blog post about it

http://internetbandaid.com/2013/05/29/installing-asterisk-pbx-on-linode/